# How to find this global minimum?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

This is a problem from a Russian school math olympiad:

```
Minimize[(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 
30)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2), {x, y}]
```

The above code is running on my comp as well as on MathematicaOnline without any response for hours. Also

```
NMinimize[(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 
30)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2), {x, y}]
```

> NMinimize::nrnum: The function value 0. +0.00126832 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {0.918621,0.716689}.

and

```
Plot3D[(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 
30)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2},PlotPoints->50 ]
```

do not help.

Comment: Did you try analytical approach?

Comment: As @Rom38 mentioned: `Solve[Thread[Numerator[Together[D[(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 30)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2), {{x, y}}]]] == 0], {x, y}, Reals]`. Then, check the solution with `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[D[(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 30)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2), {{x, y}, 2}] /. First[%]]`.

Comment: @J.M., yes, my point is that global minimum corresponds to minimum of numerator and maximum of denominator. Drawing them separately, one can see that denominator is a linear fold and numerator is a smooth decreasing slope..

Comment: @J.M.: Thank you for your suggestions. However, on that way only a local minimum  $x=5/3,y=-1/3$ is found. It's unclear whether one is a global minimum.

Comment: @Rom38: Can you kindly base your "Drawing them separately, one can see that denominator is a linear fold and numerator is a smooth decreasing slope"?

Comment: "It's unclear whether one is a global minimum." - ah, so the observation that only one real solution is returned is not sufficiently convincing, I take it.

Comment: Okay, I now see that a very good response was deleted by its author. This seems to have happened in the wake of a derogatory comment. What exactly do you expect to attain here? Some new type of MSE badge for insults? Good grief.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

My numerical solution is as follows.

```
NMinimize[{(  30 - 14 x + 5 x^2 - 10 y + 8 x y +  5 y^2)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x y - 25 y^2)^(7/2), 
 x^2 + 10 x y + 25 y^2 < 4},{x, y}, Method -> "RandomSearch",  WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

> {0.156250000000000,{x->1.66666666666667,y->-0.333333333333333}}

Addition. My exact solution is as follows.

```
Minimize[{(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 
  30)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2), 4-x^2-10 x*y- 25 y^2 >= 0} /. x -> t - 5 y, {t, y}]
```

> {5/32, {t -> 0, y -> -(1/3)}}

PS. Even the following works.

```
Minimize[(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 
 30)/(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2) /. x -> t - 5 y, {t, y}]
```

Comment: `Method -> "RandomSearch"` would be, well, "built on sand" unless you can be sure the random sampling has sufficiently covered a wide enough portion of the function's domain. As for your first: what happened to the `7/2` exponent? You are getting `5` because that is the result of evaluating your "new" function at those values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @J. M. is slightly pensive: Do you know an option of NMinimize to this end? The DirectSearch of Maple produces the same numerical  result.

Comment: There is never an assurance that `NMinimize[]` will return a global optimum except in the linear case (points 9 and 10 under "Details and Options" in the documentation). (Same goes for Maple's method.) Recall that the general procedure of such methods is to take multiple samples and take the "best" result out of all those samples, so there is still a nonzero chance of missing extrema.

Comment: @J. M. is slightly pensive: When two different CASes, making use of different methods, produce the same result, then its reliability increases, is not so?

Comment: I do not see that being any more rigorous than e.g. rmw's answer, but I suppose opinions differ.

Comment: Are you serious, taking Limit[eq, {x -> \[Infinity], y -> \[Infinity]}]
0 rigorous?, Let us call things by their proper names.

Comment: @J. M. is slightly pensive: Thank you for $7/2$. I edited my answer.

Comment: Downvotes should be based.

Comment: I did not cast a downvote, but nothing in this answer is votable, honestly. Too much faith and not enough rigor.

Comment: @J. M. is slightly pensive:  You saw rigour in the rnw's answer deleted by the author.

Answer (score 4):

The graphical solution is simple:

```
Plot3D[{
(5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 30),
(4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2)^(7/2)}, 
{x, -7, 7}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

The global minimum lies on the top of blue fold and, therefore, you need find the equation of maximum of denominator as y(x) just solving the equation for its total derivative. Further, you need find the minimum of the numerator along the earlier obtained direction.

The top of the denominator surface is:

```
ss = Solve[D[(4-x^2-10*x*y-25*y^2)^(7/2), x]+D[(4-x^2-10*x*y-25*y^2)^(7/2), y]==0, {y}, Reals]
```

It gives `{{y -> 1/5 (-2 - x)}, {y -> (2 - x)/5}, {y -> -(x/5)}}` and only last of them corresponds to top of the fold. 
Next, let's find the minimum of numerator on the top of fold:

```
Solve[#==0,x]&@D[(5*x^2+8*x*y+5*y^2-14*x-10*y+30)/.ss[[-1]], x]
```

{{x -> 5/3}}

Taking in account the `y=-x/5`, the global minimum is:

```
(5*x^2+8*x*y+5*y^2-14*x-10*y+30)/(4-x^2-10*x*y-25*y^2)^(7/2)/.{y-> -(x/5)}/.{x->5/3}
```

5/32
at `{5/3,-1/3}`

Comment: Thank you. I find it rather  a plausible argument than a solution of the problem under consideration. One of the ungrounded places is "The global minimum lays on the top of blue fold".

Comment: Minimal value of the fraction appears when you have minimum of numerator and maximum of denominator simultaneously. The fold is horizontal (4-(x+5y)^2)^7/2 and it clearly has a maximum on the top.

Comment: "Minimal value of the fraction appears when you have minimum of numerator and maximum of denominator simultaneously" . Yes, but                   Minimize[5 x^2 + 8 x*y + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 30, {x, y}]  performs   {20,{x->5/3,y->-(1/3)}} and Maximize[4 - x^2 - 10 x*y - 25 y^2, {x, y}] produces {4, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}.

Comment: -1. I don't understand the upvoter. The way the answer of @Rom38 is obtained is false. Let us call things by their proper names.

Comment: I upvoted because it is a reasonably clever, if somewhat hand-waving, approach. Next question.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtbau: Have you read my above comment "Minimal value of the fraction appears when you have minimum of numerator and maximum of denominator simultaneously" . Yes, but Minimize[5 x^2 + 8 xy + 5 y^2 - 14 x - 10 y + 30, {x, y}] performs {20,{x->5/3,y->-(1/3)}} and Maximize[4 - x^2 - 10 xy - 25 y^2, {x, y}] produces {4, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}. before voting up? I have strong doubts about that. Let us call things by their proper names: white is white, black is black.

Comment: I'm pretty much done reading any comments of yours. My advice, unsolicited though it might be, is that the comments go away.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau:  Facts are stubborn things as John Adams said.